# Screen locks after a few seconds

Tags: unity, lock-screen

Ubuntu 14.04 locks my screen after a few second. I don't always have to log in after this happens. Most of the time I do.
It's about every 20-30 seconds that I have to do this.
I have tried to change the settings and turn of screen lock but nothing seems to work.

I'm thinking of going to Windows 8 because this should be a simple fix?

Comment: Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/881125/time-to-lock-desktop and https://askubuntu.com/questions/907323/how-do-i-reduce-delay-before-locking-after-pressing-lock-button