# Time to lock desktop

Tags: command-line, unity, lock-screen

When I lock my desktop (via <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> shortcut) it takes 2-3 seconds before it happens. I don't whether it is due to the speed of my pc, but it looks more like a animation that's be playing first.

Can I change some setting to remove the animation?

Comment: Try `dm-tool lock` and `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` , those might be faster than the Super+L shortcut itself. Let me know if you want this posted as answer

Comment: @Serg I like the time that it takes to lock it. But i want that this happens when i use super+L.  And it give a "system problem detected" after i login with your trick.

Comment: You can  bind that command as custom shortcut.   As far as I know that should work. I can't find any place where super+L is set so far, but if i find, i'll add that to my answer.  I need to sleep right now, so i'll respond within 5 - 7 hours

Comment: Posted an answer, please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> shortcut calls Unity's built-in shortcut, which uses Unity's lock-screen (technically, it's `unity-panel-service` process in lockscreen mode, but that's a formality), which does use animation, and might be slower.

The alternative way, `dm-tool` allows you to lock the screen or `switch-to-greeter` (which is basically goes back to the screen that you see when you sign in). This method is slightly faster, since it involves your login screen, rather than Unity's tools. You can bind the shortcut to use `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` or `dm-tool lock` instead.

The shortcut is set within a specific compiz schema. There's two ways to go around disabling it. One, is via command-line:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/lock-screen "'Disabled'"
```

Another way is via `compizconfig-settings-manager` (which if you don't have installed, install via `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`). The shortcut is set under Unity Plugin -> General tab.

[image]

Once you have that done, you can go into System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom , and create a new keybinding for <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> with `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` as command.

Comment: Thx, Where do you get all the information? Or are you going to tel me that you remember this all?

Comment: @Erwin001  No, there's way too many tings to remember. Over time I kind of intuitively know where to look and I can use specific tools for that. For instance, I knew that since  this keyboard shortcut  is nowhere is standard settings, it must be set in compiz settings manager somewhere, so I just searched through it. To find the specific schema for the command-line method, I ran `dconf watch /` in terminal and just set and reset that via GUI, and `dconf watch /` told me where to look. It's just one of those things you pick up with experience over time