# Ubuntu Hangs When Unlocking Screen

Tags: 17.04, amd-graphics

Since my last reboot (and I assume since my last kernel update), ubuntu hangs after I return from a locked screen. I am running Ubuntu 17.04 with 4.10.0-32-generic and an Radeon RX 480 (without radeons driver).
The logs contain first

```
Aug 25 16:35:31 reichelt-desktop gnome-session[2506]: gnome-session-binary[2506]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_dbus_connection_call_internal: assertion 'object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
Aug 25 16:35:31 reichelt-desktop gnome-session-binary[2506]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_dbus_connection_call_internal: assertion 'object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
```

then a lot of failed to send message like

```
Aug 25 16:40:43 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22191.381820]  failed to send pre message 146 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22191.799677]
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22191.799677]  failed to send message 146 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22192.209455]
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22192.209455]  failed to send pre message 5d ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22192.619189]
Aug 25 16:40:44 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22192.619189]  failed to send message 5d ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:45 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22193.029952]
Aug 25 16:40:45 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22193.029952]  failed to send pre message 148 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:45 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22193.440793]
Aug 25 16:40:45 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22193.440793]  failed to send message 148 ret is 0
```

and then finally what seems like a reconstruction of some UI stuff:

```
Aug 25 16:40:46 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22194.262002]
Aug 25 16:40:46 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22194.262002]  failed to send pre message 145 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:46 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22194.672385]
Aug 25 16:40:46 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22194.672385]  failed to send message 145 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:47 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22195.493820]
Aug 25 16:40:47 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22195.493820]  failed to send pre message 146 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:48 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22195.904314]
Aug 25 16:40:48 reichelt-desktop kernel: [22195.904314]  failed to send message 146 ret is 0 
Aug 25 16:40:48 reichelt-desktop unity-settings-[2480]: failed to turn the kbd backlight off: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Keine derartige Schnittstelle »org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight« des Objekts im Pfad /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight
Aug 25 16:40:49 reichelt-desktop avahi-daemon[977]: Registering new address record for 2a02:810a:12c0:4e6c:cdd3:ea94:b14e:271e on enp2s0.*.
Aug 25 16:40:49 reichelt-desktop avahi-daemon[977]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810a:12c0:4e6c:cdd3:ea94:b14e:271e on enp2s0.
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop gnome-session[2506]: gnome-session-binary[2506]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_dbus_connection_call_internal: assertion 'object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop gnome-session-binary[2506]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_dbus_connection_call_internal: assertion 'object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop unity-panel-ser[2771]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop systemd[2163]: Starting Backing Service for the Unity Panel in Lockscreen mode...
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop compiz[2749]: WARN  2017-08-25 16:40:50 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:487 Calling method "EmitEvent" on object path: "/com/ubuntu/Upstart" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.Unity.Test.Upstart was not provided by any .service files
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop systemd[2163]: Started Backing Service for the Unity Panel in Lockscreen mode.
Aug 25 16:40:50 reichelt-desktop systemd[2163]: Reached target A target that, when running, represents the screen being locked.
Aug 25 16:40:51 reichelt-desktop compiz[2749]: Warning: Fehler beim Lesen von Daten für Kalender: Privat2. Fehlercode: READ_FAILED. Beschreibung:
Aug 25 16:40:58 reichelt-desktop compiz: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Aug 25 16:40:59 reichelt-desktop unity-panel-ser[2771]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Aug 25 16:40:59 reichelt-desktop unity-panel-ser[2771]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Aug 25 16:40:59 reichelt-desktop systemd[2163]: Stopped target A target that, when running, represents the screen being locked.
Aug 25 16:40:59 reichelt-desktop systemd[2163]: Stopping Backing Service for the Unity Panel in Lockscreen mode...
Aug 25 16:40:59 reichelt-desktop compiz[2749]: WARN  2017-08-25 16:40:59 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:487 Calling method "EmitEvent" on object path: "/com/ubuntu/Upstart" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.Unity.Test.Upstart was not provided by any .service files
```

Seems like a similar bug occured in [How do I reduce delay before locking after pressing lock button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907323/how-do-i-reduce-delay-before-locking-after-pressing-lock-button) but there it was the other way round: the lag appears when logging, not when unlocking.

It is really time-consuming if I have to wait 5 minutes before I can unlock the screen. Does this occur to anyone else? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

I did not experience this problem since I installed a newer kernel (first with mainline 3.13.2 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, just download and install with `dpkg -i KERNEL.deb`). Currently I am running my system with the kernel 4.12.4+ from https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries , which works perfectly with my hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar problem, just with a Radeon RX 560: the computer would hang for several minutes when waking up the screen or even when switching video mode. I'm using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

For me the solution was to install the `amdgpu-pro` driver (instead of the `amdgpu` that came with my ubuntu installation):
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx